# Trying to push a json obj into the value of a json obj in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to push a json obj into the value of a json obj.

```
dl = []

payload = {
  "table": ["ric-908a-dffb9c3aaac3"],
  "filter": {},
  "aggregations": {
    "cp_counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cp.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}

if (dl.length == 0) {
  filterAll = {
    "type": "exists",
    "exists": {
      "field": "c_fam.raw"
    }
  }
  payload.filter.push(filterAll)
}
```

I want the return to look like this:

```
{
  "table": ["ric-908a-dffb9c3aaac3"],
  "filter": {
    "type": "exists",
    "exists": {
      "field": "c_fam.raw"
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "cp_counts": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "cp.raw"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I keep getting: ERROR: payload.filter.push is not a function.  I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Because the value stored in `payload.filter` is an object and not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above code is push() is for javascript arrays but filter is an object {}. So to solve your problem you should do this

```
payload.filter=filterAll
```

instead of

```
payload.filter.push(filterAll)
```